# How to customize or make it auto height of wicked_pdf header footer in rails2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, ruby-on-rails-2, wicked-pdf

I have plugin called `Custom_header_footer_plugin` to replace the content of `wicked_pdf.rb` file so that we get an option to change or `customize the content of header and footer` in pdf report, so if i give the content of header or footer more than 3 lines and save the format, in my pdf report it will take `only  last 3 lines` rest of the `lines it will cut off` so how can i `break the default margin size` ie,  to `break the default height of header or footer` in my pdf report so that i can display more than 3 lines of header or footer in my pdf report.